# Contact form results duplicate messages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, contacts

This really baffles me. This is the php and js for the contact form. When testing the contact form I am receiving duplicate messages and I have no idea why this is happening. I've reviewed the php code over and over again and I can't tell why this is happening. It seems correct to me :/ 
I've also contacted my web hosting service support just in case and they told me that the problem must be on the code. In the question I've uploaded both PHP and JS. If you need me to change the provided code into something that would actually help you let me know please. Thank you in advance :)

UPDATE : (firebug data on XHR)  1 request
What you think? Is it the backend or the frontend? :/ 
(I see no errors though) :(

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Thu, 12 Mar 2015 20:47:21 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5
Server  Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.37
view source
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  58
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    www.mydomain.com
Pragma  no-cache
Referer Ηttp://www.mydomain.com/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

PHP

```
    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "myemail@mydomain.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Do you have firebug on your firefox? launch firebug and go to the XHR and look for multiple requests. Its you're making a single request its definitely your backend code, not the frontend. Check that first. I don't see any duplicate mail function in your backend script. Why did you label your backend code as CSS?

Comment: oh my mistake hehehe :P I was reading the css code while I was posting the question :)

Comment: @unixmiah can you give it a look? I get one request but like you said there is no error on the php code. :/ so what is it?